# Integrating Apply with LinkedIn to Ionic InAppBrowser

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, linkedin-api, inappbrowser

I have a website that uses the AWLI widget of LinkedIn for "Apply with LinkedIn" feature.This widget has an iframe which has "SignIn with LinkedIn" button if user is not logged in and once user logged in,it changes to Apply with LinkedIn.This feature works in the website.

But the issue is when i try to integrate the website within Cordova InAppBrowser after sign in there is a blank screen and the flow is stopped.

Please help in understanding what is the issue to make it occur only in InAppBrowser.

https://www.linkedin.com/mjobs/awli/awliWidget

Please find the steps and screenshot link below:

Step 1:

[I have this button from the widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QW2vp.png)

Step 2:

Once I clicked the Sign In with LinkedIn,the next page opens where user can enter their linkedIn credentials.

[Sign In Page opens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vczJn.png)

Step 3:

After I enter the valid credentials ,white blank screen comes.

[Blank Screen Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1Nit.png)

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Could you please cut your screenshot to make it better readable or even better add any errors/logs as text?

Comment: could you please show us the network page of the "blank screen issue"

Comment: The network page is empty too